# Select index using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code, it's for carousel indicators i made some changes to it by putting images instead of the default indicators, how can i select the data-slide-to="0" to any of the li's and apply a condition to it, for example if data-slide-to = 0 change navbar background color to red, using jquery function?
i have a navbar above the carousel, what i want to do is to select the index for indicator and when it becomes active it changes the navbar background color

```
<!-- Indicators -->
            <div class="controls">
                <ul class="nav list-unstyled list-inline">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
                        <a href="#"><img style="width: 100%" src=""></a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1">
                        <a href="#"><img style="width: 100%" src=""></a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2">
                        <a href="#"><img style="width: 100%" src=""></a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3">
                        <a href="#"><img style="width: 100%" src=""></a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="4">
                        <a href="#"><img style="width: 100%" src=""></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li[data-slide-to="0"]').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: i added the code in the following link to show you what i want to do, can you help with fixing it please? it only takes the first if and applies the action to it
https://jsfiddle.net/ckf2o6zg/

Comment: @stephjhonny If your question doesn't correctly describe what you are trying to accomplish, you should edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

If style changes are all you need, this can be done with pure CSS.

```
li[data-slide-to="0"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: i added the code in the following link to show you what i want to do, can you help with fixing it please? it only takes the first if and applies the action to it jsfiddle.net/ckf2o6zg